# ubuntu server 16.04 не обновляет список пакетов

Tags: linux, ubuntu, сервер, apt-get

установил ubuntu server 16.04, настроил по инструкциям, а сейчас не могу ничего установить. при выполнении `sudo apt-get update` сначала думает долго потом выдает ошибку 101 "network is unreachable". при установки чего либо сначала все проверяет, а когда дело доходит до связи с пакетами, то такая же ситуация. как все исправить?

Comment: нет доступа в сеть

Comment: @alexanderbarakin это понятно. вообще он соединен. доступ по ssh есть.

Comment: тогда имеет смысл внимательно проинспектировать подключенные репозитории и поискать упоминание `proxy` в конфигурации *apt*: `$ tail -n 100 /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/*`